# Python Pandas Dataframe: Duplicating data in one row to multiple rows with the same value and merging rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, group-by

I've been trying to create a script to clean up some data but I'm having trouble and have been unable to find the information. I could also be searching for the wrong thing.

I've got a CSV with data that contains a large number of columns and rows. I'm trying to merge rows together. There should only be 1 line for each 'Repeat_Instance' and the empty 'Repeat_Instance' row needs to be in each other row. I've mostly got it working by using a pandas `groupby` command except for the first row of an ID needs to be copied to each subsequent row with the same ID.

Here is a short example of the dataframe/table:

| Record_ID | Repeat_Name | Repeat_Instance | DataInFirstRepeatName | Data_In_check_current | Data_In_Assessment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  | A |  |  |
| 1 | check_current | 1 |  | B |  |
| 1 | check_current | 2 |  | C |  |
| 1 | assessment | 1 |  |  | D |
| 2 |  |  | Z |  |  |
| 2 | check_current | 1 |  | Y |  |
| 2 | assessment | 1 |  |  | X |
| 2 | assessment | 2 |  |  | V |

In the end, it should look like this:

| Record_ID | Repeat_Name | Repeat_Instance | DataInFirstRepeatName | Data_In_check_current | Data_In_Assessment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | check_current | 1 | A | B | D |
| 1 | check_current | 2 | A | C |  |
| 2 | check_current | 1 | Z | Y | X |
| 2 | assessment | 2 | Z |  | V |

For actual code, I have this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv')

df_joined = df.groupby(['Record_ID', 'Repeat_Instance'], sort=False).max().reset_index()

df_joined.to_csv('complete.csv', index=False)
```

I've been unsuccessful with copying that first row of a Record_ID to each row. I thought using pandas `concat` may be the solution but I've had no luck. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Extract a dataframe with the first row for each `Record_ID` (`.groupby(...).first()`)and `.merge()` them with the other rows on `Record_ID` to copy the the values to other rows.

Comment: Is the data you want from the first row always only the `DataInFirstRepeatName` column or can there be others?

Comment: @Alexk I'll attempt the .first and .merge and look at the documentation with those in mind thank you.

Comment: @Shaido Yeah that's correct. Each iteration of 'Repeat_Name' don't repeat. So there won't be additional data that'll conflict in the columns.

Comment: @Shaido I don't believe I can edit my comment. But to clarify, the data in each different 'Repeat_Name' don't shared columns with other 'Repeat_Names'.

Comment: @Ciecmah: I added a potential solution, it works for the example data you have here but you can check so the logic is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can propagate the `DataInFirstRepeatName` information in the first row to the others using the forward fill function [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html). When this is done, simply drop the first row in each group (can be done using e.g. [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) on a suitable column).

```
df['DataInFirstRepeatName'] = df.groupby('Record_ID')['DataInFirstRepeatName'].ffill()
df = df.dropna(subset=['Repeat_Name'])
```

Then apply the other row merging logic (here with `first`):

```
df.groupby(['Record_ID', 'Repeat_Instance']).first().reset_index()
```

Result:

```
   Record_ID  Repeat_Instance    Repeat_Name DataInFirstRepeatName Data_In_check_current Data_In_Assessment
0          1              1.0  check_current                     A                     B                  D
1          1              2.0  check_current                     A                     C               None
2          2              1.0  check_current                     Z                     Y                  X
3          2              2.0     assessment                     Z                  None                  V
```